# How to establish a TCP connection in Ruby without causing an exception if connection can't be made?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm writing a simple network analyzer in Ruby and want to try connecting to all the ports on a machine:

```
(1..65535).each do |port|
  socket = TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', port)  
end
```

Problem is when a port doesn't connect, I get a Ruby error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 1
```

I know I can catch the exception:

```
(1..65535).each do |port|
  begin
    socket = TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', port)
  rescue => ex
    puts "problem: #{ex}"
  end
end
```

But it feels a bit ugly to use exceptions for this purpose... knowing that I won't be able to connect to most ports. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What is your goal, when you can't connect on a port? What do you want to happen?

Comment: That purpose (i.e., error handling) is what exceptions were designed for.

Comment: I was hoping there was an option to specify a callback if the TCP connection couldn't be made or something less serious as an exception. Exceptions have backtraces and other information that doesn't make sense in this context when the problem isn't really an exceptional issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Inline Rescue

You might just ignore unopen sockets with an inline rescue. For example:

```
require 'socket'
sockets =
  (1..65535).map { |port| TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', port) rescue nil }.compact
```

You're still rescuing the exception, but you're essentially throwing it away as irrelevant to you. You can then do something with the **array of open sockets** stored in *sockets*. As one example:

```
sockets.map &:addr
```